# A famous TeX error message

Tags: knuth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interwoven alignment preambles are not allowed - what exactly does this mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28186/interwoven-alignment-preambles-are-not-allowed-what-exactly-does-this-mean)

This question was inspired by [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/are-there-any-latex-easter-eggs).

D. Knuth list this error message in TB:
`If you have been so devious as to get this message, you will understand it, and you deserve no sympathy.`

Is there someone who has never had this error message? What can be the procedure to obtain it?

Comment: As far as I know, the message error is "Interwoven alignment preambles are not allowed." and D. Knuth comment is "If you have been so devious as to get this message, you will understand it, and you will
deserve no sympathy." (TeXbook, page 299).

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28186/14100)

Comment: @ScottH. I see. Thanks for the link and sorry for the duplication of the thread.

Comment: No apologies necessary :)

Comment: _"Is there someone who has never had this error message?"_ Yes there are lots of people. For example, I have never had this error message. (Also, all the people who have never used TeX.) :-)