# Fun: How can we generate funny/unexpected messages in LaTeX?

Tags: fun, terminal-output

Knuth says in "Chapter 6: Running TeX" of the TeXbook:

> **Error messages** can be terrifying when you aren't prepared for them; but they **can be fun when you have the right attitude**. Just
> remember that you really haven't hurt the computer's feelings, and
> that nobody will hold the errors against you. **Then you'll find that
> running TeX might actually be a creative experience instead of
> something to dread.**

---

**How can we generate funny/unexpected messages in LaTeX?**

Here are my two cents:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{foobar}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{foobar}
\end{\csname @currenvir\endcsname}

\end{document}
```

yields:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{foobar} on input line 7 ended by \end{foobar}.
```

The message comes into being as follows:

1. Carrying out the `\begin`-macro—without expanding them—triggers defining a macro `\@currenvir` from the tokens that form its argument.
2. Carrying out the `\end`-macro—without expanding them—by calling the kernel-macro `\@checkend{⟨tokens that form the argument of the \end-macro⟩}`—triggers defining a macro `\reserved@a` from the tokens that form its argument whereafter `\reserved@a` and `\@currenvir` get compared via `\ifx`.

   If that comparison yields the `\else`-branch, then via `\@badend{⟨tokens that form the argument of the \end-macro⟩}` the error-message `! LaTeX Error: \begin{⟨tokens coming from expanding \@currenvir which in turn was defined from the tokens that form the argumment of the \begin-macro⟩} on input line 7 ended by \end{⟨tokens that form the argument of the \end-macro⟩}` is delivered.
3. In the scenario above the set of tokens forming the argument of the `\begin`-macro differs from the set of tokens forming the argument of the `\end`-macro. Therefore the `\ifx`-comparison, which is triggered by `\@checkend`, between `\@currenvir`, whose definition comes from the tokens forming the argument of the `\begin`-macro, and `\reserved@a`, whose definition comes from the tokens forming the argument of the `\end`-macro, yields delivering the error-message via `\@badend`, whereby
   `⟨tokens coming from expanding \@currenvir which in turn was defined from the tokens that form the argumment of the \begin-macro⟩`  and `⟨tokens that form the argument of the \end-macro⟩` expand to the same textual phrase.

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\let\elsecopy\else\AtEndDocument{\def\else{\let\else\elsecopy}}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

yields the following error-message:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{document}.
```

In this example, too, you stumble over the `\ifx`-comparison done by `\@checkend` when tracking things down:

The `\else` of the `\ifx`-comparison done by `\@checkend` for finding out if the `\begin`- and the `\end`-macro were used with the same argument is not taken for something that introduces the branch for the case of the `\ifx`-condition not being fulfilled.

---

**More funny examples are appreciated. :-)**

Comment: One day of the year, I would certainly upvote this question. Unfortunately it has come 9 months early…

Comment: Fun? [We hate](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) [fun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284390/why-do-we-hate-fun-at-stack-exchange).

Comment: This could be useful by explaining what is the problem as egreg does.

Comment: I don’t know anything about funny error messages. But once, when I was doing a very boring physics report with a fellow student, I did `\let\oldpar=\par \def\par{\oldpar And physics sucks.\oldpar}`.

Comment: @projetmbc Done. :-)

Comment: @Gaussler Nice. :-)  Why did you use `\oldpar` and not `\endgraf`  (or `\@@par`) ?

Comment: @UlrichDiez I actually didn’t really know either command. Never needed them before. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler I asked because as far as TeX/LaTeX goes, I often overlook subtle reasons for the ways people implement things.From answers to questions like "why did you implement things this way and not another" I learned a lot about the subtleties of (La)TeX.

Comment: I thought this was going to be "how can we make the error messages more meaningful?"

Comment: @UlrichDiez Cool `;-)`. I have often been thinking of creating a topic about how you can tease your LaTeX collaborators during group projects. Examples could be stuff like what I just mentioned, but also e.g. LuaTeX replacement of their names by Donald Duck or whatever.

Comment: @Teepeemm For clarification I edited the subject/title of this question... :-)

Comment: Somewhat related/crosslink: [errors - Interwoven alignment preambles are not allowed - what exactly does this mean? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28186/interwoven-alignment-preambles-are-not-allowed-what-exactly-does-this-mean)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
> pdflatex funmessage
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./funmessage.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-06-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.3 \begin{document}
```

Note that the compiler stops at `\begin{document}` saying it's missing.

How is this obtained? Simple!

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\fi}{fi}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

Never do `\renewcommand` on commands you don't know about.