# How to make TeX behave in funny, unexpected ways?

Tags: fun

Can we think of ways to make TeX behave in funny, surprising, and unexpected ways? I am looking for examples like: Redefining `\par` to make it insert a secret message between all paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\title{Stupid report}
\author{John \& Jane Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\let\oldpar=\par
\def\par{\oldpar And Android is better than iPhone.\oldpar}

\lipsum[1]

\[
    x = \frac{ - b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} } { 2a } .
\]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another example could be to swap the signs `+` and `-`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\let\oldplus=+
\let\oldminus=-

\catcode`+=\active
\catcode`-=\active
\def+{\oldminus}
\def-{\oldplus}

\[
    x
    =
    \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{ b^2 - 4ac } } { 2a }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Switching to LuaTeX obviously opens up many more possibilities, e.g. you can use a callback to replace all occurrences of specific names by “Donald Duck”.

**Can someone think of other tricks to make TeX behave in funny, unexpected ways?**

Comment: And before someone votes to close this question, please note that [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603429/fun-how-can-we-generate-nice-messages-in-latex) was allowed to stay open. So why shouldn’t this one?

Comment: As with any other type of pranks, the problem is the lack of consensus about  what is funny.

Comment: @Fran Nothing like pissing off other people with your TeX skills.

Comment: When you're late with one paragraph you should've finished, just put `\ducksay[snail]{Bear with me, I'm slow!}` there.

Comment: `\typeout{Microsoft Word V5.3}`

Comment: Also, check this question for ideas on how to slow down the compilation for your colleagues: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122116

Comment: To all of those who voted to close the question: I have now updated it so that it simply asks for tricks to make TeX behave in funny, unexpected ways. So it’s no longer about pranking anyone (other than, perhaps, yourself).

Comment: @UlrichDiez I have now updated the question so that it is no longer about pranks. Therefore, I encourage you to reconsider your decision to delete your answer. `;-)`

Comment: @campa I have now updated the question so that it is no longer about pranks. Therefore, I encourage you to reconsider your decision to delete your answer. `;-)`

Comment: [Stephen D. Hicks used TeX for writing a controller for mars-rovers.](http://sdh33b.blogspot.com/2008/07/icfp-contest-2008.html)

Comment: I recommend https://ctan.org/pkg/chickenize for these purposes.

Comment: Also relaxed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104248/what-is-the-most-bizarre-thing-you-have-seen-done-with-tex

Answer (score 5):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\let\elsecopy\else\AtEndDocument{\def\else{\let\else\elsecopy}}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

yields the following error-message:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{document}.
```

At first glimpse this looks funny.

After looking at the definitions of `\end⎵`, `\enddocument` and `\@checkend` this is not surprising any more: The `\else` of the `\ifx`-comparison done by `\@checkend` for finding out if the `\begin`- and the `\end`-macro were used with the same argument is not taken for something that introduces the branch for the case of the `\ifx`-condition not being fulfilled.

Answer (score 3):

Writing your own self-decoding TeX-encoder as described in the [11<sup>th</sup> challenge of Michael Downes' "Around The Bend" column](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/AroBend/AroundTheBend.pdf) you can turn something as obfuscated and difficult to read as

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

into something that is as short and as easy to read as

```
%%   The following snippet requires eTeX-support.                     %%
%%   For more info on minimal encoding scheme and self-decoder see    %%
%%   http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/aro-bend/answer.011         %%
\begingroup\endlinechar-1\let\+\let\+\a\def\a\c{\j\o}\+\m\relax\+\g\else
\a\b{\c7 \f\o>93 \f\o<101\c1 \h\h\f\o>125\c-93 \h}\+\j\advance\+\f\ifnum
\a\d{\catcode\o12 \uccode\o\p}\+\n\endgroup\+\l\noexpand\+\o\fam\+\p\mag
\a\q#1{\f`#1=13\k~\h\f`#1=32\k!\h\f`#1=36\k##\h\f`#1=94\k"\h}\+\k\string
\+\e\expandafter\+\h\fi\a\i{\j\p1 }\a~#1{\f\p<126\d\b\i\f\p=94\i\h\g\f\p
=126\b\b\b\b\c127 \g\d\c7 \f\o>255\c-129 \h\h\i\h\f\p>255\edef~{\a\l~\l~
####1 ####2\k E\k T}~{\+~\q\uppercase{\edef~{##1}}\e\n\e\begingroup\e
\newlinechar\e1\e3\e\relax\e\scantokens\e{\e\endgroup~}}\h#1#1}\o"6B
\begingroup\a~{\n\p13 ~\m\p32 ~\m\p94 ~\m\p36 ~~}~
;m]f+OtV$fHWzzUWs$3fHtdk;_t%3VUm]f+OtV$dkhtHH][r9]sHm~rk;tVmUm]f+OtV$d %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END OF SNIPPET
```

. Both with the further and with the latter compiling with pdflatex you get the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not funny but unexpected for people who don't know how `\endlinechar` works:

```tex
Hello world!
\endlinechar=`\e\relax
\by
```

The trailing character `e` of the name of the control-word-token `\bye` is appended to the characters of the line of .tex-input due to the `\endlinechar`-mechanism before tokenizing these characters takes place.

A bit more confusing:

```tex
Hello world!
\begingroup
\endlinechar=`y \catcode`\y=13 \def y{\string ye\endcsname}
\expandafter\endgroup\csname b
```

A nice way of writing "I must not talk in class!" ten times:

```tex
\begingroup
% \endlinechar=`\^^M\relax
\catcode`\^^M=13 %
\def^^M{\hbox{I must not talk in class!}}\par









\endgroup % Just hit return ten times.
\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Oooh, self deconding encoder is nice but I did not expect TeX to give such message like in example! :-))

```tex
% Compile this with e-TeX-support.
\begingroup\endlinechar-1\let\+\let\+\a\def\a\c{\j\o}\+\m\relax\+\g\else
\a\b{\c7 \f\o>93 \f\o<101\c1 \h\h\f\o>125\c-93 \h}\+\j\advance\+\f\ifnum
\a\d{\catcode\o12 \uccode\o\p}\+\n\endgroup\+\l\noexpand\+\o\fam\+\p\mag
\a\q#1{\f`#1=13\k~\h\f`#1=32\k!\h\f`#1=36\k##\h\f`#1=94\k"\h}\+\k\string
\+\e\expandafter\+\h\fi\a\i{\j\p1 }\a~#1{\f\p<126\d\b\i\f\p=94\i\h\g\f\p
=126\b\b\b\b\c127 \g\d\c7 \f\o>255\c-129 \h\h\i\h\f\p>255\edef~{\a\l~\l~
####1 ####2\k E\k T}~{\+~\q\uppercase{\edef~{##1}}\e\n\e\begingroup\e
\newlinechar\e1\e3\e\relax\e\scantokens\e{\e\endgroup~}}\h#1#1}\o"60
\begingroup\a~{\n\p13 ~\m\p32 ~\m\p94 ~\m\p36 ~~}~
0Siw(KwhR}Y`0Ki.=(KiZ!LhlE0nnk0hi=L5`0iKb=(KiZ!LhlWt0hi=L5`0ZLvZRbiE0glt
{0hi=L5`0ZLvZRbiE0"lm0hi=L5`0ZLvZRbiE00lt{0hi=L5`"DiooLwiJ|`nnk|`ggggggg
gggggggggggggggggggP_WW__nnk|`gggggggggggggggggggggggPV~n_ggg_-~ncV_VV__
gg_nnk|`gggggggggggggggggggggPVV_-__gg_g_g~ncdVdV~n_-VW_P_nnk|`ggggggggg
gggggggggggPdVV_g__ggg_ggg-c\#\ddV_VV]V_VP__nnk|`gggggggggggggggggggVdVd
V__g_ggg_gggg#\#\d\dV#\\dVdV-_V_nnk|`ggggggggggggggggggg+VdVV_g___gg_ggg
_##\\dd\d\dVd\\ddV_VPnnk|`gggggggggggggggggg_#VdVV___g__ggg_g+#####\dVVd
\ddVVdd_VV_nnk|`ggggggggggggggggggd#+~nVV_V__g_gggg_#####\\ddVd#\d\d+VVV
~n-nnk|`gggggggggggggggggg-#c_V_V__g_ggggg+####\#\dVdV\d\\ddd+]_nnk|`ggg
gggggggggggggggg8_V_V__g_gg_gg_#######\\dd#\\\dd\dd\_nnk|`gggggggggggggg
gggggV__V__g_g_gggg+#######\\dV+#dc\dV\dddVnnk|`ggggggggggggggggggPV_V__
g_gg_gggg#########\Vd\\dV\\dV\dd\_nnk|`ggggggggggggggggggV__V___gg_gggg_
###\8V~n~n---V\\d\V\\\V\dddnnk|`ggggggggggggggggg]_V__V__g_ggggg+#\V~n_g
-g-g--~nV\ddV\\\V\ddVnnk|`gggggggggggggggggVV__V__g_g_ggg_\V-__g_ggggg-~
n_Vc+VdV\VV\dVnnk|`gggggggggggggggg]_V_V___g__gggg+V_-___ggggg_ggg-V\+Vd
\dVVdVnnk|`gggggggggggggggPVV__V_g_g_gggg_#VV_g_gggg_gggggg-V\+V\\VddV_n
nk|`ggggggggggggggg]_VV___g__ggggg+#y]P-ggggggg_gggg_Vc\dV\dVdV]nnk|`ggg
gggggggggggPV_V_V_g_g_gggg_\_g~n8+Pggggggggggg_Vd\\V\\ddVV_nnk|`gggggggg
gggggPV_VV___g__ggggg+VdVVV~n]Pg_ggg_ggPdyddd\V\dVdVd]nnk|`ggggggggggggP
]V_V_V__g_g_ggg_\VT8~nc2-0;__ggg_P]T]PPVVdV\dVdVVVnnk|`gggggggggggPVV_V_
V__g_g_gggg+dV_~nVd++TV_gg_04-V22-0;]cVVd\VdVd]nnk|`ggggggggggPVV_V_V__g
_g_gggg_\V_g-g_g_g__gg_~nV]+dT8]dVdd\VdVV]Pnnk|`gggggggggPVV_VV_V_g_g_g_
ggg+VV_ggg_g__V_gg_gg_g__V+dVd\ddVdVV]_nnk|`ggggggggg]V_VV_V__g_gg_ggg+#
VdV_ggg__V_ggg_Vg_g_VV\ddd\dd\ddVV_nnk|`ggggggggPVVV_V_V__gg_gggg_##VdV_
_gg_VPgggg_V_gg_VV\\ddd\d\ddVV-nnk|`gggggggPVV_V__V__g_ggg_gg+##VdV_gg_g
_-~nW~n~n--_g__VV\d\dV\dVdddVnnk|`ggggggg]V_VV__V__g_g_ggg+###VV_g_gPPPP
g-__ggg-_VVd#\d\d\dd\dVV]nnk|`ggggggPVVV_V__V_g_ggg_gg####VdV_gg-VVV]]]V
V]-g_VV+#\d\d\\d\\dV~nnnk|`gggggg]VV_V_V__g_g_ggg_Vc##cV+V_g_gg-V]PP_~ng
g_VV+###d\d\\d\\ddnnk|`ggggg]VV_V_V__g__gg_gg_VVc#Vd\+V_g_--ggg-g_g__V+#
###\d\\\d\\ddVnnk|`ggggg]VVV_V__g_gg__g_g_VV8VVd\\++__g_ggg__g_V+#######
dd\\d\\dVVnnk|`ggggg]VV_V__g_gg_g_gg__V_Vcd\\\d\\+VVPPPPPV+#########\dd\
\\\dd]nnk|`ggggg]_VV__g_gggg_g_gg__V_Vc\\d\dVd\d\\d\dV##########\d\\d\\d
dVnnk|`gggggVV_V__g_ggggg__gg___V_VVc\dVddcd\d\ddV###########d\\d\\ddVPn
nk|`ggggg]V__V_g_gggg__gg_g__V_VVVVc+ddVddddddV###########d\\dd\dd\dnnk|
`ggggg-]V__g_gggggggg_g__g__V___V_cddVVdddV_c#########\d\\\d\dVVdPnnk|`g
ggggg]V_g_g_gggg-g_g__g___g_g_VV_VVcVVddV__c########\d\\\d\dVVd]nnk|`ggg
ggg]V__g_g_ggggg_g__g__V__gg_VV___VcddT8yVc#######cd\\\d\V_gV]nnk|`ggggg
g]V_g_gg_gggg_g__g___g_ggg__V_V__g_Vddd+V_#####cdV\d\d\V_g_Vnnk|`ggggggd
V_g_g_ggg_g__g_g__g_g_g_g_g__V__g__VVdd+_c###cd\dd\dcV_g_-nnk|`ggggggdV_
_gggg_g_g__g____g_gg_ggg_g__g___g_V_Vd+V_c#cd#\d\d\V__Vnnk|`ggggggd__g_g
g_gg_g_____g_ggggggg_gg_g__g_g__g_Vdd+cV\d#\\d\ddV_-nnk|`ggggggV_g__ggg_
g_g_V__g_gggggggggg_gg__g___g__VV_V9cdV#\\d\\d___nnk|`ggggggV__gg_g_g__g
__V_ggggggggggggggg_g_g___g_V_VVVc\+_cd\\#dV__nnk|`ggggggV_g__g_gg_g__V_
_gggggggg_g_ggggg_g_gg__gg__g___Vcdd\d\dVg_nnk|`gggggg-V__g_gg_g_VV_g_gg
ggggg_VVP_gggggg_gggg_gg_g_gg___cVd\dd__nnk|`ggggggg]V__g__g_VdV_ggggggg
g__VT~nVV_ggggg_gg_g_gg_gg_g_gg_cdd\V_nnk|`ggggggg]V_V__g_VdV__gggggggg_
VVcVVV_ggggggggg_g_g_g_gg_ggggcddd__nnk|`ggggggg]V__g__VVVV_g_gggggggg__
VV_g_gggggg_gg_g__g_g_gg_ggggcddd_nnk|`gggggggdV_V__g_VdV_ggggggggggg__V
_-gggggggg_g_g__gV_g_gg_gggg~ncdV_nnk|`gggggggdVV______VV_gg_ggggggggggg
ggggggggg_g__g_V_V_V_g_ggggggg~ndVnnk|`gggggggddVV__g__VV_g_ggggggg_gggg
_gggggg_g__g__g_VVVV__g_gggggg_V_nnk|`gggggggddVV_V_g__VV_g_gg_g_ggg_ggg
g_ggggg_V_g_g_VdVVV_g_ggggggg_VV\@nnk|`ggggggg-dVVV__g_Vg_g__g__gg__g_g_
ggggg_gg_VV_g_g_VdV_g_ggggggggg_VcVnnk|`ggggggggdV_g__g_gg_g_g___g__gg__
g_g_gggg__g__gg__VV_ggggggggggggg_V_nnk|`ggggggggdV__g__g_gg__V__g__g__g
__gg_g_gggggg_ggg_gggggggggggggggg_gVnnk|`gggggggg]V____g_g__VVVdV__g__V
__g___g_VV_g_g___g_g__gggggggggggggg_d_nnk|`ggggggggVV_V____VV_VVdVdddVd
VVVVdVddVdVV__g_V__g_g_V_g_ggggg_gg_g_+dVnnk|`gggggggg-VV_V___V__VVVVVVd
ddVVddVVVVVV__g___VV_g_gg_VV_g_g__g_gg_+##d_nnk|`gggggggggVVV_V_V_g__VVV
VdddVddVdVVV_V_g__g__VV__g__gg__VVP_gg__VV\##dVnnk|`ggggggggg-VVV_V__g__
_VVdVVVdVdVVV_V__gV_g_g__VV__g_g_g_g_-8Td\dVdd\\dV_nnk|`ggggggggggVVdVV_
V___VVVddVdVV_V____V_V_g_g___VV_g_gg_g_gg_+dVd\d--V-gg-_nnk|`gggggggggg-
VVV_V___g__dVVdVV_V____V_g_Vg__g___VV_g_gg_gggdddVddV_gg-nnk|`gggggggggg
g-dVVV__V___V_VVdVV_V__V_g_Vg__g_g__V___g_gg_ggddd_d-nnk|`ggggggggggggcd
VVV_VV_VV___VddVV___V___V_g_g_g_VVV_g_g_gggV--nnk|`gggggggggggg-\dVdVV_V
V_VV__VddVV_V__V____g_g_V_VdV__g_gggVnnk|`gggggggggggggcdVdVdVV_VV_V___V
dVVVdVVV____g__V_VdVV___gggVnnk|`ggggggggggggg-ddVdVVddVdVVV_V_VdVdddVdV
___g____VVVV___g_ggVnnk|`ggggggggggggggcddVVdVVdVV_VV__V_VVddVV_V__g_g_V
_VVVV_g_ggg_nnk|`gggggggggggggggcdV_V__VVddVVV__V__VV____g_ggg__VVdVV___
gg_g_nnk|`ggggggggggggggg-dVV__g__VVddVV__V__VV____g_g___VVdVVV_ggg_gg_n
nk|`ggggggggggggggggcVV_V__g_VdVddVV_V__VV__g__g___VVVdVV__gg_g_g_nnk|`g
gggggggggggggggdVVV_V____VVdddVVV_V__V_V__g_V_VddVVV_g_gg_g_g_nnk|`ggggg
gggggggggggdVV_VVV___VVVddVV_V_V_V___g___VddVV__g_g_g_g_gg_nnk|`gggggggg
ggggggggdVV__V___V_VVV_V_V_V_V__V__g_VddV_g__g_gggg_g_ggg_nnk|`ggggggggg
gggggg_VV_V_V____V_VVV_V_V_V_V_Vg_g_VdV___g_g_g_g_g_gg_gg_nnk|`ggggggggg
ggggggV_V_V___V_V_VVV_VV_V_VV____g_VVV__g__g_gg_g_gg_g_nnk|`gggggggggggg
gg_V_g__V_V_VVV_V__VV_VV_V__g_g_VV__g__g_g_g_gg_g_g_gggVnnk|`ggggggggggg
gg_V_g_V____VV__V_V_V_V_V___g__g_*dV__g_g__g_g_g_gg_g_ggV_nnk|`ggggggggg
ggg_V_g_g_g__V_V_VV_VV_VV_VV_VV__g_gV_V__g__g__g_g_g_g_g_g_0;1nnk|`ggggg
gggggg_V__g___g__g__V_VV_VV_VVV_V__V__g_g__V__g__g__g_g__g_g_gP040;nnk|`
gggggggggggVV_V_g___V__g__V__VV__VV_V_V_V_V_g_V_V___g__g__g_V__g__m11_nn
k|`ggggggggggfVVV_V___V_V__V__V__VV_VV_VV_VV__V__V_V__V____g__V_V__V_040
;~n-nnk|`gggggggg04m0;VVV_VV___V__V__V___VVVVdV_VdV_V_V_VV_VV__V_V___V__
VV1m1-__g_nnk|`gggggggggVgVV_V__V_V__V_V__V_VdV_VVdVVVdV_VdVV_dV_VV__V_V
_VV_Vfm1f__g_nnk|`gggggggg_VVgVVdV_V__VV_VV_VV_VVdVVVdVV_VdVV_VVdVV_VVV_
VV_VdVV04g0;V_V__gg_nnk|`ggggggggVVdV_~nVV_V_V__V_V_VVVVddVVVVddVVVddVVV
VddVVVV_VVdVVm11VV_V_gggg_nnk|`ggggggggVVdVVVP04--0;11VV_V_VV_VVdddVVVdd
dVVdddVVdVVVVV_VdV~ncm1V_-g_ggg_nnk|`ggggggg_VVVdVVdVVWVmmmVV__VVV_VVVVd
ddVdVVdVVddVVdVVVdddd04g0;P0;g_gggg_g_g_nnk|`ggggggg_V_VVdVVddVd04P0;04g
g0;mm0;V_VV_VVddVdVddVdVdVVVdddm11~n_#V#_ggg_g_g_nnk|`ggggggg__g_V_VV_Vd
VdVdd\\dmmmg-0;11VddV1VddVdddVV1104~n0;mmffqqc#g_g__g_g_g_nnk|`ggggggg_g
__g__V_VV_VVddVddVdddP04m1m~n~n0;~gmVdddV04m110;__+#cg+qqqqdg__g__g_g_nn
k|`ggggggg_V__g_g_VVdVddd\\ddVd\d\\04m0;P#m11104g0;#mm+##\##-Pqqqqqq__g_
g_gg_nnk|`gggggg_V_V_V__g_g__Vd\\\ddVVVV_-_##dddd##qd##########cg+qqqcV#
d_g__g_gg_nnk|`ggggggVV_V_V_V_V__g_g--_-g__g__V_##dddV##d###########-g_q
VV#_#d__g_g_g_nnk|`ggggg_VV_VV__VV_V_V_V_g_gg__g_VV+##qqqd+#\##d\######c
g___VV#_##g___g_g__nnk|`gggggVV_VV_VV_VV_VV_V_V__g_g_VVV##qqqqdV_Vc##\#8
#\c#dg__VdV\W-~n--_V_g_g_nnk|`ggggVV_VV__V_V_V__V_V_VV_V_g_g_V##qqqVdqqV
#####y##+#-g__dV#_ggVgg-V__g_nnk|`gg_VV_V__V___V___VV_V_VVdVV___d##VqqqV
qqVy#####dV#cgg__dVcggg_gggV___g_nnk|`gggV_V_V__V_V_V__V__VVVddVddV~n__#
~n_c#qqVqq#######d_dg___dcdggg_gg_VV_g__nnk|`ggV_V_V_V_V_V_VV___V_VVd\d-
gWg_g_~ncd#\qVqdd##cfd#y#dg___\cggggg_ggVV__g_nnk|`g_VV_V_V_V_V__V__g__V
Vd\dVW_gg_g_gg~n-dqVqqdc#dgq##cgd___\dgggg_gggVVV___nnk|`VV_V_V_V_V_V__g
___V_Vd\\\dV_-g_gggg_qqqVqq_##+q#\+gd__+#dgggg_ggggVV___nnk|`VV_VV_VV_V_
V____g_V_Vd\\d\d~n_g__ggggVqqqVqqV#\\d###+dP+\\dggggg_ggVVV___nnk|`VVV_V
_V_V_V_V__g_V_VVd\\\\dVgg__ggg-VqqqVqqV#c~n~n_dPcV-V\\d_gggg_gggVVV__nnk
|`VV_VV_V_V__V__g___VVdd\\\\dVggg_gggV_qqqVqqqdV_-_gggg~nWc\Vgggg_ggggVV
_V_nnk|`VVV_VV__V__V__g__V_Vd\\\\\d-ggg_ggggVVqqVqqqdV_+_g_gg~nc\\gggggg
_gggVVV__nnk|`VV_VV_VV_V___g___VVVdd\\\d\ggg__ggggVd+qVqqqd\\\Vgg_gg_V#d
gggg_ggg_VVV__nnk|`VVV_VV_V_____g__V_VVdd\\d\\ggg_gggggVVqqVdqqd\\cg_ggg
gg~nc_g_g_g_ggVdVVV_nnk|`V_VV_V_V___g___V_VVddd\\\d\gggg_ggggdVqqVqqc\##
dg_ggggggd__g_V_g_g_dVV_Vnnk|`VV_VVV_V____g__V_VVddd\d\\\_gg_gggggV~nqqV
qqqcdcdgg_g_gggVV__V_g_g_dVVVV_nnk|`VVV_VV_V___g__V_V_VVdd\d\c~nVggg_ggg
g-Vqqdqqqcdd+gg_gggggg-VddV__V_ddVVV_nnk|`VV_V_VV___g___V_V_Vddd\\c-gVgg
_ggggggdqqdqqqcVVV+g_ggggggg-VqVqqqqdddVV_nnk|`VVV_V_V_V__g___V_VVddd\c-
ggVggg_gggggqqqdqqqqgg~nVgg__ggggg~ndqVqdqdVddVV_nnk|`VV_VV____g___V_VVV
dd\\c-gg_Vggg_ggggg-VqqdqqqgggVgg_gggggggc\VqqqVddVV__nnk|`V_V_V__g____V
_VVddd\\c-g__VVg_g_ggg_ggVqqdqqqgggVggg_g_gggggcdqqqVdddVV_nnk|`VV_V____
g__V_VdVd\\\cV_VV~ng-V_g_ggg_g_Vqqdqqqggg-Vggg_gggggggcqqqdddVVV_nnk|`VV
_V_V___V_VVddd\d\c_g_ggg_g-qV__g_V~nWVWqqqq-gggg-_gg_g_gggggqqq\dddVV__n
nk|`V_V_V_V_V_VVdd\d\\~ng_gg_ggg__qqq_V_qqqV_VP~nggggggg]ggg_g-W_gggqq+\
ddVVV_nnk|`VV_V_V_V_VVddd\\\~ng_g_g_g__V_qqqqVqqqqqV_VgggggggggVgg_ggg-W
_gq+\\dddV__nnk|`V_V_VV__V_Vddd\\~n_g_gg_g_g_VV_qqqqVqqqqq_V_ggggggggVgg
g_gggggg-c\\dddVV_nnk|`VV_V_VV__Vdddd\c___g_g_gg_VVdVqqqqdqqqqqggVgggggg
gggVgggg_g_ggggc\\ddVV_nnk|`V_V_V_V_V_VdddcV_V__g__g_VdcVVVqqqqdqqqqqPV_
ggggggggV+ggg_ggg_g__c\ddVVVnnk|`VV_VV_VV__VVdcVVV_V_g_VVdV~ngggg-qqqqdq
qqqV_VggggggggV\+gg__g__g_VVcdddV_nnk|`V_V_VV_V__VVdcVVVdVV_Vc~ngg_gg_gg
~nqqqqqqqqqqVgg_gggggV\\+_g_V_VVqVq]cdVV_nnk|`VV_VV_V___VdcdVdVdVddcg_g_
g_g_g_g_~nqqqqqqq~n_g_g_g_ggV\\+dqVqqVqqqqqq_V__nnk|`V_V_VV_V__VdcV_Vddd
\cg_g_g_g_g_g_g_g_~nqq~n_g__g_g_g__V88\+qqqqqdqqqqqqV__nnk|`nnk|`X|`"iKb
whR}Y`0ZoKLDigovRY0iKbZoKLDi0S<iEND OF SNIPPET
```

Comment: What is the point in using an ASCII-art-generator like [https://asciiartattack.de/en/imagegenerators/beginners/#ascii-image](https://asciiartattack.de/en/imagegenerators/beginners/#ascii-image) and wrapping the result into a `\message`-command before applying the self-decoding TeX-encoder?