# Bug with multicol, hyperref and \refstepcounter

Tags: hyperref, counters, multicol

In the following MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{counterForCalcul}
\setcounter{counterForCalcul}{0}
\def\incrementCounterForCalcul{\refstepcounter{counterForCalcul}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

there should be two columns but there is only one.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you say you're experiencing, i.e., I get two columns with four lines each, not just one column.  My system runs MacTeX2021 (all updates installed), LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1, L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>, `multicol` 2019/12/09 v1.8, and `hyperref` 2021-06-07 v7.00m. Please tell us more about your computing setup.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, my distribution is older... I solved the issue by replacing `\ refstepcounter` by `\stepcounter `

Comment: Just curious: how old is your TeX distribution? Incidentally, if you plan on creating cross-references to the items, you'll be unpleasantly surprised if you're using `stepcounter`.

Comment: What is the command to know how old it is?

Comment: You need to look at the first few lines of the log file. If your tex file is called `main.tex`, the log file will be called `main.log`.

Comment: I'm a bit ashamed... 2017

Comment: Any chance you can update your system to a current version of TeXLive or MikTeX?

Comment: Since I'm maintaining a project with many people involved, having an old distribution might be actually a good thing.

Comment: Of course, depending how much time you and your coauthors have at hand, making a collective effort to update everyone's TeX distribution might not be a bad idea either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't happen with TeX Live 2020 (or later), `multicol` version 1.8y and `hyperref` version v7.00k.

It happens with TeX Live 2019 with `hyperref` version 7.00d.

You can work around the issue by emitting `\leavevmode` before `\refstepcounter`, which I'd recommend anyway, because it will produce the anchor in the expected place.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{counterForCalcul}
\setcounter{counterForCalcul}{0}
\newcommand\incrementCounterForCalcul{%
  \leavevmode
  \refstepcounter{counterForCalcul}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test

\incrementCounterForCalcul Test
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I generated the picture by running TeX Live 2012, so it should be safe with all later releases.

Avoid `\def` in documents, unless you have specific reasons to use it. See [Fun: How can we generate funny/unexpected messages in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603429/4427) for a funny example.